# Bootstrap dropdowns are already open on mobile resolution

Tags: javascript, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm using bootstrap on a site, and the navigation is bootstrap responsive navbar. It collapses properly, but when I click the button to open it, dropdowns are already open.

[image: Like this.]

They wont close if I tap them, or so.

Here's the code for the nav:

```
<div class="navbar-inner" id="navigradi">
    <div class="container">
    <a class="brand pull-right navbar-text" href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/">
     <img src="http://materia.hurttiajahuumoria.fi/hh-logo-smaller.png" alt="Hurttia & Huumoria"  class="hidden-phone hidden-tablet"/>       
     <span class="hidden-desktop">Hurttia & Huumoria</span>   
      </a>

      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>
    <nav class="nav-main nav-collapse collapse" role="navigation">
        <?php
          if (has_nav_menu('primary_navigation')) :
            wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'primary_navigation', 'menu_class' => 'nav'));
          endif;
        ?>
      </nav>  
    </div> 
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you put the generated HTML in a JSFiddle so we can see a live example of the issue?

Comment: are you using a mobile device to get the above, undesirable result? If so, what device and version? I looked in Chrome and IE9 and everything looks fine.

Comment: @MichaelFreake I don't think you understood the question. The problem is that **all dropdowns** are already open in the navigation, and it produces a very long list.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help you as what you see is totally different from what I see: http://imgur.com/qH0yuEM

Comment: Try resizing your browser window to match mobile resolution. You will end up with the same resolution as I.

Comment: Deleted the url as I do not want search engines to link here with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug in Bootstrap v2.1.1.

I compared the CSS of your site with my own and saw that the CSS related to `<ul class="dropdown-menu">` has the `display: block;`.  The CSS from 2.1.1 is:

```
@media (max-width: 979px)
.nav-collapse .dropdown-menu {
position: static;
top: auto;
left: auto;
display: none;
float: none;
max-width: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0 15px;
background-color: transparent;
border: 0;
-webkit-border-radius: 0;
-moz-border-radius: 0;
border-radius: 0;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
-moz-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;
}
```

However, I'm using 2.3.0 and the CSS for the `dropdown-menu` class has `display: none;` as seen here:

```
@media (max-width: 979px)
.nav-collapse .dropdown-menu {
position: static;
top: auto;
left: auto;
display: none;
float: none;
max-width: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0 15px;
background-color: transparent;
border: 0;
-webkit-border-radius: 0;
-moz-border-radius: 0;
border-radius: 0;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
-moz-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;
}
```

You could do a couple of things.  Override the Bootstrap CSS and set `display: none;` for this particular `@media (max-width: 979px)` query as is done in v2.3.0.  Or you could simply try updating your entire Bootstrap version to the latest.  That's what I would try first.

Let me know what you decide.  Interested in the result.

Comment: Well, the css solution closes the dropdowns, but also makes them unopenable. I'll take a look at this, later today. (It's 2:14 AM here). Thanks!

Comment: There may be additional differences than just the `display: none` I found, so I still think your best bet is to update to a newer version of Bootstrap.

Comment: The problem is that the site is live, and some of the layout code is also made in bootstrap.css.

Comment: I updated bootstrap-responsive.css, and the dropdowns are working!

Comment: Awesome!  Well done.  That was the suggestion in my answer above so please feel free to accept that answer if you feel it applies. Cheers.